# How can I keep a script running in the background-not working

Tags: php, filepath, popen, ratchet, pclose

I am trying to fire up the Ratchet's chat-server.php file which is needed to fire up the socket server from a php file so that whenever a client visits the page the server is started but its not happening. This chat-server.php file needs to be run from the terminal but I am trying to run it from the main page on user visit.

**FILE STRUCTURE**

> ./index.php
>
> ./config.php
>
> ./vendor/(all vendor files)
>
> ./src/MyApp/Chat.php
>
> ./js/app.js
>
> ./inc/connect.php     <--Database connection file
>
> ./inc/send-message.php
>
> ./inc/startServer.php
>
> ./inc/bg.php
>
> ./inc/serverStatus.txt
>
> ./css/index.css
>
> ./css/reset.css
>
> ./bin/chat-server.php

**config.php**

```
<?php
    include_once ("./inc/startServer.php");
?>
```

**chat-server.php**

```
<?php

    use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
    use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
    use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
    use MyApp\Chat;


    if(isset($startNow)){ 

            require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

            $server = IoServer::factory(
                new HttpServer(
                    new WsServer(
                        new Chat()
                    )
                ),
                8080
            );

            $server->run();

    }

?>
```

**bg.php**

```
<?php
    $startNow = 1;
    include_once ("../bin/chat-server.php");
?>
```

**startServer.php**

```
<?php

$statusFile = dirname(__FILE__).'/serverStatus.txt';
$status = file_get_contents($statusFile);
if($status == "0"){

        function execInBackground($cmd) {
                if(substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "WINDOWS") {
                    pclose(popen('start /B ' . $cmd, 'r'));
                    file_put_contents($statusFile, 1);
                }
                else {
                    exec($cmd . ' > /dev/null &');
                    file_put_contents($statusFile, 1);
                }
        }

        execInBackground("php " . dirname(__FILE__) . "/bg.php");

}
```

?>

**serverStatus.txt**

Its default value has been set to **0**

**NOTE:** Updated the code accordingly but doesn't work still now.

**Plus** I don't have any idea about restarting the server incase of any failure or how to shutdown the server when all clients leave.

Comment: I really dont find why this question was a downvote but still thanks for it.

Comment: You are starting a new server for every client? Why do you need to manually start  the server instead of having it just running on  the background? This question just screams XY problem.

Comment: @PeeHaa, nope, this code should start only one server for all the clients. Take a look, there is a check about server status.

Comment: Why are you manually starting server(s) to begin with? Again: [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @PeeHaa Firstly I am using Ratchet for building the chat app. And in the Ratchet docs we are asked to start a file named `chat-server.php` from the terminal which will open up the web sockets. So we need to start them manually (in WIN). In *nix we can use supervisord. So imagine on a public server to use the chat app the admin needs to go into the terminal everytime the user wants to use it.

Comment: No the admin doesn't need to do that every time a user wants to use it. You start the server once. Does the admin manually start apache when a client wants to view your webpages?

Comment: nopes..he doesnt as it is a public server like hostinger.in

Comment: @PeeHaa, I missed a point and that is I need it manually incase the server fails while working I need it to restart again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you including files using **relative paths** you must remember that they are relative to the **current *running* file**, not just to **current file**.

In your case. When you accessing `index.php` and including in it `config.php` and from then `startServer.php` it's all ok, because you are including `./inc/startServer.php` which is right, relative to `index.php`.
But than you are including `../inc/serverStatus.txt`, which is not right, because you are still running `index.php` and that relative path resolves to `/../inc/serverStatus.txt` in other words you are trying to access a file that is one level higher than your `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. So you will never get into your `if` statement.
You can use a `__FILE__` constant which is always resolves to the absolute path of the **current file**. So you can change your `$statusFile` to

```
$statusFile = dirname(__FILE__) . '/serverStatus.txt';
```

Next thing is regards your `exec()` and `popen(pclose())` commands. If you want to execute some command that is not in your `PATH` environment variable, than you **must** specify an absolute path to your file. Because you don't know from which folder it will be started. It may be started from `Apache` home dir or maybe started from your user's home dir. It depends on the setup of your `PHP` is it `sapi` module or is it `fcgi`. Anyway, you need to change your `execInBackground()` to

```
execInBackground("php " . dirname(__FILE__) . "/bg.php");
```

And add some spaces in your commands, like this:

```
pclose(popen('start /B ' . $cmd, 'r'));
exec($cmd . ' > /dev/null &');
```

this way you will not have some strange errors that might occur.

In your **bg.php** you need to change current working directory, like this:

```
<?php
    $startNow = 1;
    chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
    include_once ("../bin/chat-server.php");
?>
```

This way, `PHP` will find `chat-server.php` no matter from what folder you will run it.

BTW, how did you planning to stop your server? =)

---

**UPDATE**: Also you have a **variable scope** issue in your function `execInBackground()`. Your function relies on the variable `$statusFile`, but this variable defined in the **global scope** and is not visible inside the function. To make it visible, you must include statement `global $statusFile;` in your function before accessing `$statusFile`. Like this:

```
    function execInBackground($cmd) {
            global $statusFile;
            if (false !== stripos(PHP_OS, 'win')) {
                pclose(popen('start /B ' . $cmd, 'r'));
                file_put_contents($statusFile, 1);
            } else {
                exec($cmd . ' > /dev/null &');
                file_put_contents($statusFile, 1);
            }
    }
```

and I've changed the way you are checking the OS, because your approach contained an error.

---

**UPDATE2**:

After a bunch of tests, I figured out that when php-script running in the background (under Windows) it can't use "echo()" to write to STDOUT. When it happens, php-script will silently die, with no errors. So change all `echo()`'s to some log-function.

Change listening port to some other, that is free for sure, like 50000. Because, 8080 is often may be already taken by some web server or other service.

And remember! You can start your chat server only if you have your own server (like VPS/VDS or dedicated server), on the **public hosting** no one will allow you to open some port for incoming connections for security reasons. On the public servers there are often disabled functions like `exec()`, `popen()` and similar for the same reasons.

Comment: I really don't know how to stop the server. Maybe when all the user leaves it should stop plus I need a way to restart the server incase it fails somehow.

Comment: I changed the way you said but it still gives me 'disconnected'.

Comment: the changes made causing some awkward problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read http://php.net/manual/es/function.shell-exec.php

Note that this function is disabled when PHP is running in safe mode.

Comment: My localhost isn't running in safe mode plus I copied the code from http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php. And it was about running some background process.